# Entity Framework Core update column with foreign key reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is the simplified version of the table structure I have:

```
[Table("PolicyMapping")]
public class PolicyMapping
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Policy PolicyA { get; set; }
    public Policy PolicyB { get; set; } 
    public Lookup_Bank Bank { get; set; }       
}

[Table("Policy")]
public class Policy
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string PolicyNm { get; set; }    
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}

[Table("Lookup_Bank")]
public class Lookup_Bank
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public string Code { get; set; }            
}
```

I am working on the edit screen for policy mapping where you can have the same values for PolicyA and PolicyB attributes.

After using automapper for DTO to the entity, here is my entity object looks like:

```
var policyMapping = new PolicyMapping
{
    Id = "b27fb632-330b-46be-a649-2e2463d58626",
    PolicyA = new Policy
    {
        Id = "a4f1cf6f-034d-4727-ab8f-49e95b2c9d23",
        PolicyNm = null,
        Description = null
    },
    PolicyB = new Policy
    {
        Id = "a4f1cf6f-034d-4727-ab8f-49e95b2c9d23",
        PolicyNm = null,
        Description = null
    },
    Bank = new Lookup_Bank()
    {
        Id = "98ed2bae-631b-490c-8ddf-3e02232d4231",
        Name = null,
        Code = null
    }
}
```

I am mapping only selected id value of dropdown to entity id using automapper. Values are present for `Code`, `Description` and other attributes in the database. It's just not getting populated after automapper.

```
dbContext.PolicyMapping.Attach(policyMapping);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is the error, I am getting

> The instance of entity type `Policy` cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'a4f1cf6f-034d-4727-ab8f-49e95b2c9d23'} is already being tracked.
>   When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

The reason for the error maybe because I am attaching two different entities with the same Id. I am still not sure how can I make it work in the most efficient way?

**Solution 1**: (not efficient)

```
var fromdatabase = dbContext.PolicyMapping.Include(x => x.PolicyA)
        .Include(x => x.Bank)
        .Include(x => x.PolicyB)        
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == policyMapping.Id);

fromdatabase.PolicyA = dbContext.Policy.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == policyMapping.PolicyA.Id);
fromdatabase.PolicyB = dbContext.Policy.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == policyMapping.PolicyB.Id);

dbContext.PolicyMapping.Attach(fromdatabase);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is working. But I would like to avoid a trip to the database just to fetch the entire entity.

**Edit: Based on Xing's answer**

@Xing, pointed out to change the Model structure by adding navigational properties and some changes in `OnModelCreating` method. (This method is currently blank in my code)

However, I went through a couple of articles ([This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio) & [This](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/aspnetcore-application)) related to EF Core Code First approach, none of them are saying about navigational properties and all.

I am wondering how they are updating the column in this scenario?

Comment: What is the lifetime of your `dbContext` object? It should be a short-lived object so you shouldn't run into issues with multiple instances with the same entity identity unless you're reusing the same `dbContext` for multiple operations.

Comment: I am using `services.AddDbContext`. So I think its default one. One per request. I am updating the PolicyMapping on Post request.

Comment: "two different entities with the same Id" - that _is_ your error, which seems somewhat obvious; it's not much of an "identifier" if the value can be duplicated. What is the reasoning for using that value twice?

Comment: Lets you have a Policy with Rule A & Rule B. In a day, for the first 12 hours Rule A will get executed and after that Rule B will get executed. But you can set up the same rule to get executed for both the times. This is part of the requirement.

Comment: So, technically "PolicyA" and "PolicyB" can be the same policy, NOT two distinct policies which happen (if the table allowed it) to have the same Id value?

Comment: @TiesonT. That's right

Comment: Worth noting, in your "Solution 1", that `dbContext.PolicyMapping.Attach(fromdatabase);` is not necessary, since `fromdatabase` is never in a detached state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197972/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-shaggy).

Answer (score 0):

If you just would like to update the Id of the navigation properties, you could add foreign key for them and update it.

1.Model:

```
public class PolicyMapping
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid PolicyAId { get; set; }      
    public Policy PolicyA { get; set; }

    public Guid PolicyBId { get; set; }
    public Policy PolicyB { get; set; }

    public Guid BankId { get; set; }
    public Lookup_Bank Bank { get; set; }
}
```

2.DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PolicyMapping>()
            .HasOne(x => x.PolicyA)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<PolicyMapping>(p => p.PolicyAId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PolicyMapping>()
            .HasOne(x => x.PolicyB)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<PolicyMapping>(p => p.PolicyBId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PolicyMapping>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Bank)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<PolicyMapping>(p => p.BankId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    }
```

3.Add migrations.

4.Controller:

```
 var policyMapping = new PolicyMapping
        {
            Id = new Guid("b27fb632-330b-46be-a649-2e2463d58626"),
            PolicyAId = new Guid("a4f1cf6f-034d-4727-ab8f-49e95b2c9d23"),
            PolicyBId = new Guid("a4f1cf6f-034d-4727-ab8f-49e95b2c9d23"),
            BankId = new Guid("98ed2bae-631b-490c-8ddf-3e02232d4231")

        };
        dbContext.PolicyMapping.Attach(policyMapping);
        dbContext.Entry(policyMapping).Property("PolicyAId").IsModified = true;
        dbContext.Entry(policyMapping).Property("PolicyBId").IsModified = true;
        dbContext.Entry(policyMapping).Property("BankId").IsModified = true;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then you could retrieve `PolicyA` or `PolicyB` from their foreign key `PolicyAId` or `PolicyBId`

```
var policyA = dbContext.Policy.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == policyMapping.PolicyAId);
```

Comment: Though I haven't tried it I am thinking your code will work. The only problem is I have around 20 Entities (With many properties), each tied with one another through the same structure described in the question. This will require a lot of code changes and running the migration scripts again.